# Llenar campos NULL usando LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo 2 tablas, una con productos y fechas y otra tabla solo de fechas, mi idea es poder extraer un detalle de las fechas que **NO** coinciden o no están en la tabla A:

TABLA A

| PRODUCTO | FECHA |
| --- | --- |
| abc | enero/2022 |
| abc | marzo/2022 |
| abc | mayo/2022 |

TABLA B:

| FECHA |
| --- |
| enero/2022 |
| febrero/2022 |
| marzo/2022 |
| abril/2022 |
| mayo/2022 |

Y necesito obtener algo como lo siguiente:

| PRODUCTO | FECHA |
| --- | --- |
| abc | febrero/2022 |
| abc | abril/2022 |

He intentado haciendo un LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT A.PRODUCTO, B.FECHAFROM A LEFT JOIN B ON (A.FECHA= B.FECHA) WHERE B.FECHA IS NULL
```

pero obtengo valores NULL en el campo REF

| PRODUCTO | FECHA |
| --- | --- |
| null | febrero/2022 |
| null | abril/2022 |

y me gustaría ver el registro abc que ahí tengo en la tabla A en lugar de NULL.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias poner un ejemplo mas claro?

Comment: Y que queres que diga en lugar de null???

Comment: Ademas, creo, que tu pregunta no es lo que estas preguntando, y cuando te demos una solucion, no te va a servir porque tus tablas reales no son asi...

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Lo siento, es mi primera vez y me costó un poco crear el formato de tablas para que el ejemplo fuera más claro. Lo que quiero que diga en lugar de NULL es lo que está en el campo REF de la tabla A, ahí mostré una tabla de lo que quiero obtener. Gracias

Comment: pero no entiendo.. quieres que invente un dato cualquier al mezclar las tablas? yo dudo que tus tablas tengan esa informacion asi..

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score -2):

-- Another option:
SELECT DISTINCT A.PRODUCTO, B.FECHA
FROM A JOIN B ON TRUE
WHERE (A.PRODUCTO, B.FECHA) NOT IN (SELECT producto, fecha FROM A)

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Explica en ambas respuestas cómo funciona la consulta, y no olvides dar el formato correspondiente. Recuerda además que OP hizo la pregunta para _Oracle_.